# Construct an $Q$ orthogonal using Givens matrices that for all unitary vectors $x$ and $y$ we have $Q^Tx=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Find a method to use given matrices to create an orthogonal matrix $Q \in R^{n \times n}$, that for unitary vectors $x,y$ $\in R^{n}$, $$Q^Tx=y$$

The ideia that i have is: take a sucession of Givens matrices $G_n...G_1y=x$, the $G_n...G_1$ must be $Q$, how $Q$ is ortogonal matrix, just take the transpose to $Q^Tx=y$. But the problem is the Givens matrices.

Comment: What IS the question? Given $x$, $y$ construct $Q$ such that $Q^Tx=y$?

Comment: Yes, yes, is this the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use  [Householder transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation):
The idea is 
$$
Q^T x = x - 2 (x^Tv)v.
$$
with some $v$ with $\|v\|=1$.
By the condition
$$
y = Q^Tx = x-2 (x^Tv)v
$$
it follows that $v$ is a multiple of $x-y$. Set $v:= \frac1{\|x-y\|}(x-y)$.
It remains to show that the matrix defined by
$$
Q^Tx = x-2 (x^Tv)v
$$ 
indeed does the job:
$$
\begin{split}
Q^Tx-y &= x-y - \frac2{\|x-y\|^2} x^T(x-y)\cdot (x-y)\\
& = (x-y) \|x-y\|^2\left( \|x-y\|^2 - 2x^T(x-y)\right)\\
& = (x-y) \|x-y\|^2\left( -(x+y)^T(x-y)\|x-y\|^2  \right)\\
& = (x-y) \|x-y\|^2\left(\|y\|^2 - \|x\|^2  \right) = 0.
\end{split}$$

Comment: Yes, this Q is a ortogonal, but is made by Householder, you choose v to be the bisectrix between x and y to build Householder reflection, right. But i need a Givens rotation, from x to y, maybe exist a formula between Householder reflections and Givens rotations, that alow to use this argument that you show.